# TemplateSyntaxError at /taskapp/taskapp-board/ Could not parse the remainder: '(status='new')' from 'tasks.filter(status='new')'

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, jinja2

i got an error called "TemplateSyntaxError", i created a project that handle tasks in this app i create task-board.html page that handle user's task i create 3 section for it 1 section add new task 2nd in-progress tasks, and 3rd completed task, if i want to start that task move new tasks section to inprogress section with help of drag and drop same gose for inprogress to completed section

## task-board.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Task Board</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        .task-section {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="task-section" id="new-section">
    <h3>New</h3>
    <div class="draggable" id="new">
        {% for task in tasks.filter(status='new') %}
            <div class="task" id="task_{{ task.id }}">{{ task.title }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="task-section" id="in-progress-section">
    <h3>In Progress</h3>
    <div class="draggable" id="in_progress">
        {% for task in tasks.filter(status='in_progress') %}
            <div class="task" id="task_{{ task.id }}">{{ task.title }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="task-section" id="completed-section">
    <h3>Completed</h3>
    <div class="draggable" id="completed">
        {% for task in tasks.filter(status='completed') %}
            <div class="task" id="task_{{ task.id }}">{{ task.title }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".draggable").sortable({
            connectWith: ".draggable",
            update: function(event, ui) {
                var taskId = ui.item.attr("id").split("_")[1];
                var newStatus = ui.item.parent().attr("id").split("-")[0];
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/update_status/" + taskId + "/" + newStatus + "/",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Handle success if needed
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        // Handle error if needed
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        $(".draggable").disableSelection();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>


# Views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Task


def task_board(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'taskapp/task_board.html', {'tasks': tasks})

# models.py
from django.db import models


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=[
        ('new', 'New'),
        ('in_progress', 'In Progress'),
        ('completed', 'Completed'),
    ], default='new')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# taskapp/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import task_board

urlpatterns = [
    path('taskapp-board/', task_board, name='task_board'),
]

# todo_project/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('taskapp/', include('taskapp.urls')),
]
```

## Error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /taskapp/taskapp-board/

Could not parse the remainder: '(status='new')' from 'tasks.filter(status='new')'
```

[TemplateSyntaxError1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjuPY.png)
[TemplateSyntaxError1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAR8S.png)

Comment: Share the corresponding view.

Answer (score 0):

Django Template Language doesn't support calling functions that require arguments. You're getting the errors from the `.filter(...)` methods. You need to do all the filtering in the view, not in the templates.